# Span not applying to all things in it

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for a class and I need a part of the `<p>` to have a certain padding but it's only applying to the first line.

The HTML is :

```
<p>
Some text
<span class="tabulation">
                    Une ambiance conviviale
                    <br>
                    Durant l'été, une grande terrasse ensoleillée
                    <br>
                    En hiver, une verrière chauffée
                    <br>
                    De l'espace de stationnement
                    <br>
                    Un chef cuisinier d'expérience
                    <br>
                    Des salles privées pour les repas de groupe
                    <br>
                    Un menu pour enfant
                    <br>
                    Une vue sur le fleuve
                </span>
</p>
```

What happens is that the span only applies to the first line. I know it's from the br, but I don't know how could I make it work. Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Instead of using span to wrap the break points, you could wrap every line into a span and simply display them as block or flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, try making your span `display:block` or `display: inline-block`

```css
.tabulation {
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
Some text
    <span class="tabulation">
        Une ambiance conviviale
        <br>
        Durant l'été, une grande terrasse ensoleillée
        <br>
        En hiver, une verrière chauffée
        <br>
        De l'espace de stationnement
        <br>
        Un chef cuisinier d'expérience
        <br>
        Des salles privées pour les repas de groupe
        <br>
        Un menu pour enfant
        <br>
        Une vue sur le fleuve
    </span>
</p>
```

Also, see [understanding inline box model](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the `<br/>` element - I would use spans with `display: block` applied to them - this will force them to be on individual lines and will allow you to apply styling directly to them for the padding etc.

Alternatively - if the children items are a list with the text at the top as a heading - you could use a `<ul>` or a `<dl>`. The advantage of a `<dl>` is that you get the `<dt>` element to provide the headings and the `<dd>` elements are already block level elements so you just need to space them out as  desired.

```css
.tabulation span {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.tabulation dd {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<p class="tabulation">
  Some text (using spans to show the items)
  <span>Une ambiance conviviale</span>
  <span>Durant l'été, une grande terrasse ensoleillée</span>
  <span>En hiver, une verrière chauffée</span>
  <span>De l'espace de stationnement</span>
  <span>Un chef cuisinier d'expérience</span>
  <span>Des salles privées pour les repas de groupe</span>
  <span>Un menu pour enfant</span>
  <span>Une vue sur le fleuve</span>
</p>

<hr/>

<dl class="tabulation">
  <dt>Some text (using a DL to show the items)</dt>
  <dd>Une ambiance conviviale</span>
  <dd>Durant l'été, une grande terrasse ensoleillée</dd>
  <dd>En hiver, une verrière chauffée</dd>
  <dd>De l'espace de stationnement</dd>
  <dd>Un chef cuisinier d'expérience</dd>
  <dd>Des salles privées pour les repas de groupe</dd>
  <dd>Un menu pour enfant</dd>
  <dd>Une vue sur le fleuve</dd>
</dl>
```